# Rails - how to fetch all (unique) data through has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, unique, has-many

I've these models:

**cars**:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :car_services, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :car_services
end
```

**cars**:

```
class CarService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :service
end
```

**service**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
  has_many :cars, through: :car_services
end
```

I have in a variable saved all cars that are matching a criteria, like:

```
@cars = Car.where('shipped_at = ?', params[:shipped])
```

Now is in `@cars` saved several cars and each car has a list of services. I am trying to get a unique list of all services for these cars and in the format `Service A, Service O, Service P`.

How to do that? There's a way to iterate through all `@cars`, then save each service into an array, than call `.uniq_by {|x| x["service_id"]}` on that array and then print it out.

Is there a more effective way to do it? I think like in this work-flow is too many steps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Rails 4 (possibly earlier):

```
service_ids = CarService.where(car: @cars).pluck(:service_id).uniq
Service.where(id: service_ids).pluck(:name)
```

Substitute `:name` for the `Service` field that contains the strings you are after (use `.map` as needed.)

Comment: I believe this should work in rails 3.2, possibly even 3, but I seem to recall pluck being introduced in 3.2...

Comment: Actually I recommend @JiříPospíšil's answer over this one, since his results in a single SQL query.

Comment: @user984621 I think Matt is correct. Jiří Pospíšil's version is a single query with a subquery, but still means it'll hit the DB one less time. (Edited: Sorry, pinged the wrong person)

Answer (score 2):

You can approach the problem from the other side and do this (resulting in a single query):

```
Service.joins(:cars).where(cars: {id: Car.where(shipped_at: params[:shipped])}).uniq.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Nice - confirmed results in single query.